# AutoComplete not working in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

When I go to create a new message in Outlook 2007, and I start typing the first few characters of a contact's name, no suggestions appear.  I've just added all my contacts from a .csv file that was exported from Yahoo! Mail.  If I type the name out, then click 'send', then it will ask me which of the contact's emails to send it to if the contact has multiple addresses.  I've looked in the advanced options to make sure AutoComplete is on, which it is.  What is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These addresses are stored in a file called an NK2 file, if its a new installation, you'll need to wait for sometime [5 to 6 days] before this file gets some addresses to suggest.

Or you can manually edit this file and put your recently used addresses in the file: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_autocomplete.html

Click above for details.