# Autocomplete for Outlook addresses has stopped working

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The autocomplete function of MS Office Outlook 2003 has stopped filling in the email addresses.
The only thing I can think of which changed is that I upgraded to Windows 10.
Help?
Thank you for any suggestions,
Lowell

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoComplete not working in Outlook 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/124543/autocomplete-not-working-in-outlook-2007)

Comment: Outlook 2003 is not compatible with Windows 10: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Microsoft+Office+Outlook+2003&ModelOrVersion=11&Vendor=Microsoft&Locale=1033&LastSearchTerm=&BreadcrumbPath=&TempOsid=Windows+10

Comment: @thims: that explanation would mean that the proposed duplicate isn't relevant.  How about posting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let's clarify: [Outlook 2003 is not compatible with Windows 10](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Microsoft%20Office%20Outlook%202003&ModelOrVersion=11&Vendor=Microsoft&Locale=1033&LastSearchTerm=&BreadcrumbPath=&TempOsid=Windows%2010). It lost Windows compatibility starting from Windows 8.

Please consider to upgrade to the latest version. I personally recommend [Office 365](https://products.office.com/en-US/compare-microsoft-office-products).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Outlook 2003 click on the Tools Button in the ribbon at the top of the page
2. click Options
3. click Mail Format
4. uncheck the boxes "use microsoft Office word to edit" and "use microsoft Office word to read"
5. click OK

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean MS Office Outlook 2013?

This helped me for Win7/8:
https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=38759

Be sure to save your files before you edit/delete them.

Answer (score 0):

There IS a work-around.
Just start typing the address in the FROM box and it WILL autocomplete the address AND keep it. Then drag it into the To, Cc or Bcc boxes as necessary.
Inexplicable but true.